# Bash Scripting custom output

Tags: bash, command

I'm beginner in Bash Scripting and I need to assign to a variable a custom command output,not the entire command just a part of it.Is there a way I can do that?
The command:

```
gtf 1600 720 60
```

The Output:

```
# 1600x720 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 44.76 kHz; pclk: 93.10 MHz
  Modeline "1600x720_60.00"  93.10  1600 1672 1840 2080  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
```

What I want to store:

```
"1600x720_60.00"  93.10  1600 1672 1840 2080  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in the variable? I assume it is the output of the command in my answer.

Comment: I want to store from this output 1600x720 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 44.76 kHz; pclk: 93.10 MHz Modeline "1600x720_60.00" 93.10 1600 1672 1840 2080 720 721 724 746 -HSync +Vsync this  "1600x720_60.00" 93.10 1600 1672 1840 2080 720 721 724 746 -HSync +Vsync

Comment: You can use the backtick/subshell syntax from my answer. Just send the output of the command via pipe (`|`) to the sed command, e.g. `your_command | sed 's/^.*Modeline //'`

If the command writes the output to `stderr`, be sure to redirect first: `your_command 2>&1`

Comment: You can improve your question by adding the command you are running, its output, and the relevant part of the output that you want to store in the variable.

Comment: @AlexandruWorld : So you also want to catch the last line of the output without the word _Modeline_? Or was this just an example, and the format can vary? And  I guess the output is stdout and not stderr, right?

Comment: Yes the last line  without Modeline ,the format can vary and the output is stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to arrive at your desired output, but I like grep:

```
gtf 1600 720 60 | grep -Po '(Modeline)\K(.*)'
```

Here you would be using a regular expression with grep to capture any output on a line that follows "Modeline".

Then you can use command substitution to store the output in a variable:

```
OUTPUT=$(gtf 1600 720 60 | grep -Po '(Modeline)\K(.*)')

echo "$OUTPUT"
# "1600x720_60.00"  93.10  1600 1672 1840 2080  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your command in backticks to store its output:

```
a=`echo Hello`
```

Alternatively, you can also use `$()`:

```
a=$(echo Hello)
```

If you want to store only a part of the output, you can pipe the output of your command to a postprocessing script, e.g. `sed`:

```
a=$(echo foo | sed 's/foo/bar/')
```